# How can i resize the surfaceview of android video recording application?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, video-recording

Application is allowed to record a video of size 640X480 .

Surface-View shows the stretched preview of camera .

What should be the appropriate Height and Width in dp of Surface-View for the preview size 640X480.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn about how transforming SP to DP, for example:

```
float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density